# Crosses instead of circles on GoogleChart

Tags: google-visualization

It is possible to display crosses on google chart instead of circles?

I cannot find it in the documentation.

Comment: The dev team just introduced the capability to change the point shapes in the latest release candidate version, but it is as-yet undocumented, so I do not know if they support crosses.  I shall inquire on your behalf as to whether they are supported or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The new `pointShape` option does not support crosses per say, but you can make the "star" shape look like a cross:

```
pointShape: {
    type: 'star',
    sides: 4,
    inset: 0.1,
    rotation: 45
},
pointSize: 16
```

Load the release candidate version (1.1) instead of the production version (1) to test this.  This should be available in the next public release, tentatively scheduled for March 13, 2014.

Comment: awesome! https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=en#!topic/google-visualization-api/iJk86uE6Tbk